# Sending file in lan without a client/server solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file, networking, lan

I working on a windows forms project, visual studio 2010, c#

I want to send some files to computers in our network but they don't have a "listener" as in client/server solution but i do have username/password. Is there any way to send files knowing this information? And as i said, i do not want to build a client / server solution.

Cant i use "Impersonate" somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the username password and your client is within the same domain, you might be able to use UNC with authentication (with $) and send the files to client PC. Something like: `\\clientPC\c$`. Once authenticated, you can just use File IO, e.g. `File.Copy(..."\\clientPC\c$\yourfile.txt")` to send file.

You can use the [class posted here for UNC authentication](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/0cbd77b7-5c6c-4a86-bc3a-e06eb888fa17).

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the same domain as your machine? If so, do you have the ability to create a share?  If you can, you may be able to just setup a share and transfer the files as you would locally.  If this is possible there is no point in creating a verbose application for a trivial need.

I built similar for a company I used to work for, the "client" exposed a share and me; the "server" simply used File.Move() to transfer files.

Comment: Mark : I am building a windows forms that needs to be able to transfer file automatically through the domain

Comment: How is client expected to open the file? Through an explorer window?  If they need access to the file through the OS, then setting up a share and moving the file to the share location is the easiest least verbose way of accomplishing your task.

Comment: This will be an exe that starts automatically with windows, noone opens this manually

Comment: Not sure I understand you.  A windows form is executed manually by a user or a scheduled task.  If you want something to start when Windows does and start transferring files I would suggest a Windows Service.  I wanted to know how the client is supposed to open the file, because if expected to be opened from a folder then my solution would fit your needs.  You won't have to fiddle around with impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use impersonate,
[Read this article](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/28269-Upload-File-Network-Path.aspx)
 , Maybe it will helpful.